# Issues in searching through the vector?

Tags: c++

I have a vector of the form given below (in C++):

```
 vector<pair<int,int> > u;
```

Now when the first element of u.first becomes equal to 12 then I want to break from the loop. I am using the following code for this:

```
 while(1){
    if((find(u.begin().first, u.end().first, 12)!=u.end().first))
            {
                    break;
            } 
   }
```

However, it gives me the error that

```
     'unable to resolve identifier first'
```

Comment: The answer from James is a good fix for this.  I'll point out a few other things.  One, note that `begin()` and `end()` return iterator types so `.` is not valid on them.  Two, even if you *could* operate on them, `end()` doesn't refer to the final element; it refers to one position *beyond* that and is therefore never valid to use except as a terminator.  A `vector` contains special non-iterator methods named `front()` and `back()` that are useful when you want to inspect values directly.  (That's just FYI; in this case, you can't really refer to the elements anyway; see James' answer.)

Comment: It's dangerous, if find return false , while become infinite.

Answer (score 1):

`std::find` iterates over a range and returns an iterator to the first element in the sequence that matches the provided value (`12`, in your case).  The iterators are not the element in the container, they are pseudo-references to elements in the container.

You have to dereference an iterator to get the element.  So, `u.begin()->first` would be the `first` value of the initial element of the container.  `u.begin().first` is nonsensical.

In any case, to find a matching element using an operation other than `==`, you need to use `find_if` with a custom predicate.  For example, using a lambda expression:

```
auto const it(std::find_if(u.begin(), u.end(), [](std::pair<int, int> const& v)
{
    return v.first == 12;
}));

if (it != u.end())
    continue;
```

Comment: also it does a return...what does this return imply...'continue' or 'break'

Comment: It is a lambda expression.  `find_if` will call the lambda for each element, and the lambda returns `true` if the element is a match.  `find_if` will then return the iterator to the first element for which `find_if` returns `true` (or `u.end()` if the lambda returns `true` for no element).  You then need to compare the iterator with u.end()` to see whether a match was found.

Comment: Here, it is again giving that unable to resolve identifier 'v'